# Making UPDATE for coordinate does not return the same value

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geojson, coordinates, spatial-query

Being totally new with PostGIS, I am trying to UPDATE one of my column on my table.

The column itself is called 'center_point' with type of `GEOGRAPHY(Point,4326)`

```
UPDATE cities
SET center_point = st_setsrid(st_makepoint(-6.28381815,106.804863491948),4326) WHERE id = 1;
```

Upon verifying the result:

```
SELECT id, st_asgeojson(shape) AS "geojson", st_asgeojson(center_point)
FROM cities WHERE id = 1;
```

I am getting a different output:
[image: The coord does not match with what i entered]

- It says that the coordinate is -6.283... , 73.1951...
- Where i am expecting it to be -6.283.... , 106.80486

Can anyone help me why the result is different?

Comment: did you recieve an error? `ST_MakePoint` expects it's parameters in (X, Y) order, i.e. (Lon, Lat); you pass them in wrong order (there can't be Lat > 90°).

Comment: @ThingumaBob clumsy me. Thanks for pointing that out. It works now. Can you please put this an answer so that i can accept it. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The simple answer:**

`ST_MakePoint`, as most functions in PostGIS (and OGC conform software), expects the order of coordinates passed in to be `ST_MakePoint(X, Y)`, i.e. `ST_MakePoint(lon, lat)`.

Your second paramter exceeded 90°, so I assumed you mixed them.

---

**Interesting note:**

While PostGIS' *geometry* type **doesn´t care for the input values of a given coordinate pair** in a given CRS (it will happily accept `INSERT/UPDATE ST_SetSRID('POINT(0 100)::geometry), 4326)` into/on a table with specified `geometry(POINT, 4326)` column), the *geography* implicitly **denies out-of-bounds coordinates and will simply substract the difference from the bound**.

Example:

- WGS84 (and quite universal) bounds of latitude is `90°`
- you passed in `106.80486°`
- you got `90 - (106.80486 - 90) = 73.19514`